# eye coordinates in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to know how to get the eyes coordinates in pixels (left eye and right eye) in opencv i'm using this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier)

I want to get the coordinates and print them. This is the part getting the eyes position:

```
for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
               {
                 Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );

                 int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
                 circle( image, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );



               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but a suggestion. 
1) use an OpenCV to detect face on image ( you've made this)
2) use dlib to detect landmarks on detected face
3) take landmarks with appropriate indicies 36-41for left eye and 42-47 for right eye and use their coordinates to calculate eye coordinates

Comment: thak you for your answer, but i think it's quite simpler than that i won't be needing to use dlib or anything, because the eyes detector already draws circles around the eyes in any image i process and give me the results i want